# Cannot import module with Lua, results in attempt to index global 'test' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, importerror

Without success I have attempted to import my own Lua files into other scripts using the require keyword but whenever I attempt to call any functions contained within the imported module (e.g. "test.lua") I reach the subsequent error:

```
require 'test'
test.method(args)
==> yields error: 
==> Attempt to index global 'test' (a nil value)
```

I've added the file to the package.path in case this was the issue, but again there was  no beginning error indicating that it cannot find the file in Lua's pathway.

```
package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/test.lua"
require 'test'
test.method(args)
==> yields error: 
==> Attempt to index global 'test' (a nil value)
```

I'm running an interactive Lua shell from the directory where the file is. When attempting to print the local variable name, e.g. local test = require "test" the value is nil.

```
package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/test.lua"
local test = require 'test'
print(test)
==> nil
```

Thoughts? (Note: I also required the file in general without assigning it to a local variable and printed its values again with nil as the returned value.)

Comment: Put your code here. We cannot telepath.

Comment: Updated, again it was blowing up right from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on lhf's answer:

The Lua shell reads one statement at a time. It then loads the code string with the `loadstring` function (or more accurately, the C API equivalent), which compiles the Lua code and returns a function that executes it. Since each statement is loaded separately, and produces a different function, they don't share local variables.

Essentially, this console input:

```
local test = require "test"

print(test)

if test then
    bar()
end
```

Is translated to this:

```
(function() local test = require "test" end)()

(function() print(test) end)()

(function()
    if test then
        bar()
    end
end)()
```

(Note that this applies to files as well. Lua 'files' are actually just functions with an implicit `function(...)` signature. This means you can return from the top-level of a file, as well as perform any operations you can do on functions (sandboxing, etc) on files as well.)

If you're copying code from somewhere, you can surround the code in `do ... end`, like so:

```
do
    local test = require "test"
    print(test)
end
```

The `do ... end` block counts as one statement, and scopes local variables.

Comment: Beautiful! By adjusting my test.lua to return [the entirety of the methods contained within it on a table object](http://hisham.hm/2014/01/02/how-to-write-lua-modules-in-a-post-module-world/), I am able to access the methods properly when I require it inside my Lua shell.

Answer (score 1):

In the interactive Lua shell, each complete statement is executed as read. Local variables do not survive from one statement to the other.

Comment: Well, when I use the Lua4Crypto I can --     local crypto = require "crypto"    and call methods on that variable with no error. Lua4Crypto was installed with luarocks so clearly I am misunderstanding how to import my own files into both the interactive Lua shell and my Lua scripts in general. (>.<)

Comment: @LorenaNicole, in your third example, try removing `local`.